# yum install gives "No package available"

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I try to install package with `yum` install:

```
yum install salt-master
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package salt-master available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I search for this issue, but don't find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow steps mentioned on link to install salt-master

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/rhel.html

it will not be available in default repository

Comment: This happens also with every other package

Comment: What is the RHEL release you are using ?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Comment: Try this one       http://lpar.ath0.com/2012/09/10/yum-unable-to-read-consumer-identity/

Comment: I did it, but I still get `Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package salt-master available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Its good sign, consumer identity error gone. Please make sure you have installed epel repository as mentioned in the comment. Then provide "yum update" to update repository and then provide "yum install salt-master"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57406/discussion-between-ganeshragav-and-or-smith).